# what are the steps to integrate JIRA and Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, interface, jira, integrate

I want to integrate JIRA with Jenkins so as to update tickets automatically when a job is build successfully or failed.
I have established JIRA and Jenkins server separately both working properly.I have the following JIRA plugins in Jenkins installed:-

1) Jira Issue Updater
This plugin can update Jira issues by changing their workflow status and adding comments.
1.11

2) JIRA plugin
This plugin integrates Jenkins to Atlassian JIRA.
1.39

3) JIRA Plugin for Jenkins
This plugin implements the Application Link API to support integration with Atlassian JIRA
1.5.3

4) JiraTestResultReporter plugin
This plugin creates issues in Jira for failed unit tests.

Following add-on in JIRA server:-

1) JIRA Plugin to integrate Jenkins CI
Version: 1.5.3
Vendor: Marvelution
Add-on key: com.marvelution.jira.plugins.jenkins

2) JIRA Plugin to integrate Hudson CI
Version: 5.0.4
Vendor: Marvelution
Add-on key: com.marvelution.jira.plugins.hudson

I want to build a job in Jenkins and wants the issue to be generated automatically in JIRA if the build Passes/Fails.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this [plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.marvelution.jira.plugins.jenkins)..it may helps you to get what you need..

Comment: Thanks nuwan I have installed the above plugin before hand only.
As I mentioned above I have configure both jenkins and jira .
I can see the jenkins jobs in jira but I am not able to update build information from jenkins i.e update issues etc on jira from jenkins only 
Please help regarding that.
Thnks.

Comment: I think you better to add this information into the question also.provide more details will helps to find solution ASAP